# Monograph on harmonic analysis with applications to PDEs

Tags: reference-request, harmonic-analysis, elliptic-pde, textbook-recommendation, parabolic-pde

"There are two ways to teach mathematics, namely the systematic way and the application-oriented way"- E. Zeidler

I'm a fresh researcher on PDEs, especially interested in evolution equations in abstract spaces, and recently switch to a more application-oriented field. My most frequently used tools are the ones from (linear or nonlinear) functional analysis and basic PDEs theory. When I engage deeply in studying some concrete PDEs problems, I need to study the **quantitative properties** of solutions or functions in some certain function spaces, which more or less related to **harmonic analysis.** Unfortunately, I do not have the chance to learn this tool systematically.

So my question is **"Are there some monographs on harmonic analysis that put emphasis on applications to PDEs?"**, just like the "nonlinear functional analysis and its applications" by Zeidler to "functional analysis". Any suggestion on reading it/them will be appreciated. Although the theory of "pseudo-differential operators" stems from the distribution theory and Fourier analysis, I tend to exclude it from "harmonic analysis", since it is quite independent.

Comment: I think the books of Hörmander count as such...

Comment: Thank you. But I tend to believe that "the pseudo-differential operators theory" is an independent topic. Actually, I have learnt basic results of this theory.

Answer (score 3):

H. Bahouri, J.-Y. Chemin, R. Danchin, Fourier Analysis and Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations is a good one.

Comment: That is so great! Thank  you. I have to say that is EXACTLY what I want.

Answer (score 2):

[This excellent book](http://imcs.dvfu.ru/lib.int/docs/Math/unsorted/%C0%ED%E0%EB%E8%E7/Stein,_Harmonic_Analysis,_Real-Variable_Methods,Orthogonality,&Oscillatory_Integrals,1995.pdf) by Elias Stein gives you a rich resource on Harmonic Analysis and prepares for PDE needs. It's accessible online.